# Trouble connecting to gpsd

Tags: c, linux, gps, gpsd

I have a board with Linux Ångström running on it.
Now i wan't to get GPS Data in my programm. So i set up a gpsdeamon who gets his gps informations from a modem.
The deamon works well and if i telnet  to localhost:2947 (which is the standard port for gpsd) i reveive a bunch of json strings from the deamon, like this:

> {"class":"TPV","tag":"GGA","device":"/dev/ttyUSB2","mode":3,"lat":51.282822633,"                          lon":11.404333250,"alt":327.500}

So gpsd seems to be set up correctly.

But in my C-Programm i can't get a connection to this port and i don't know why. My Code looks like that:

```
#include <gps.h>
struct gps_data_t *gpsdata = 0;

int main() {
if(gps_open("localhost", "2947", gpsdata)<0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not connect to GPSd\n");
        return(-1);
    }
/* some more stuff */
}
```

The problem is, that the function gps_open() always return -1. All libraries  seems to be installed correctly.
Do you have any idea, what i can try to make it work?

Comment: ?WATCH={"enable":true,"json":true}

Comment: thats the command i typed to telnet, to get json enabled.
but it doesn't help to get my program running

Comment: it must be sent to gpsd otherwise gpsd won't return anything via the socket

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the error using gps_errstr function, something like the following

```
#include <errno.h>
...

int main()
{
    if(gps_open("localhost", "2947", gpsdata)<0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not connect to GPSd (error %s)\n",
                gps_errstr(errno));
        return(-1);
    }
    /* some more stuff */ 
}
```

However, the problem is that `gps_open` needs a pointer to a valid (**not null**) `gps_data_t` structure, something you can have declaring gpsdata this way

```
struct gps_data_t gpsdata[1];
```